# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, mono

Viva Pessoal,

Sou novo no mundo .NET, C#, EntityFramework (Microsoft world). Estou a trabalhar em um projeto com as tecnologias mencionadas, inicialmente estava a programar numa VM(com Windows) porque uso MAC mas tive alguns problemas de performance e decidi abandonar a VM e também porque já existe [suporte para MAC](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-mac.html).

Consegui efetuar as configurações e a aplicação corre sem problemas, exceto quando tenho que lidar com campos do tipo `DateTime`, seja ao persistir na base ou apenas lendo. Abaixo o stacktrace. 
**Nota:** Estou a usar o [SQLServer com Docker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker)

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ErrorHandler (System.Object sender, Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsInternalErrorMessageEventArgs e) [0x00023] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs:294 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.OnTdsErrorMessage (Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsInternalErrorMessageEventArgs e) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/Tds.cs:1681 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.ProcessMessage (Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsPacketSubType subType) [0x000e6] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/Tds.cs:1721 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.ProcessSubPacket () [0x00134] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/Tds.cs:1773 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.NextResult () [0x00039] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/Tds.cs:625 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.NextResult () [0x00036] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs:1320 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader..ctor (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command) [0x00019] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs:109 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader:.ctor (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00068] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs:509 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs:764 
  at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Data.Common/src/System/Data/Common/DbCommand.cs:114 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.Common.DbCommand:ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c (System.Data.Common.DbCommand t, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext`1[TResult] c) [0x00007] in <5a182091cae84952ac9bbf3418cefa24>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1[TInterceptor].Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult] (TTarget target, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, System.Action`3[T1,T2,T3] executing, System.Action`3[T1,T2,T3] executed) [0x000f1] in <5a182091cae84952ac9bbf3418cefa24>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader (System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) [0x00042] in <5a182091cae84952ac9bbf3418cefa24>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00046] in <5a182091cae84952ac9bbf3418cefa24>:0 
  at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Data.Common/src/System/Data/Common/DbCommand.cs:114 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.Common.DbCommand:ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior)
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] identifierValues, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] generatedValues) [0x0007e] in <5a182091cae84952ac9bbf3418cefa24>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update () [0x0002b] in <5a182091cae84952ac9bbf3418cefa24>:0
```

Comment: E onde está o código que causou o erro?

Comment: Isso parece + um erro de conversão de data do SQL. Muito comum pq seu computador deve usar um padrão "humano" tipo "31/12/1982" enquanto o SQL provavelmente espera algo como o ISO "1982-12-31"

Comment: @jean como faço para alterar isso? Eu ja tentei alterar o formato da data utilizando o GUI do MAC mas parece nao resultar.
LeandroAngelo, nao achei relevante colocar o codigo porque acontece com qualquer operacao de leitura ou persistencia de datas e como falei no Windows funciona normalmente

Comment: Depende do seu código. Mas se funciona em uma máquina e não em outra verifique o padrão de data em ambas e como foi setada a língua no SQL server (se não for tudo no mesmo sever)

Comment: @jean, é isso o problema é que ñ consigo fazer essa alteração, pelo menos utilizando o UI do OS, acredito que deve ser feito na linha de comando, já pesquisei tudo e nada.

Comment: set language, set dateformat pesquise pelo MSDN e mude no SQL Server